# Enabling blending makes renderPipelineState fail to build in MetalKit MTKView

Tags: swift, metal, alphablending, depth-buffer, metalkit

I'm rendering a geometry that has some translucent areas (alpha < 1) in a metalkit `MTKView`. If `isBlendingEnabled` is left as false in the descriptor for the render pipeline state, then everything displays as it should (albeit with all solid colours).

I'm aware that rendering translucent objects depends on the draw order. For the time being, I just want to test what alpha blending looks like with the translucent areas blended with what is already in the render buffer, even if it's just blending through to the background (at this point still just the clear colour).

However, when I try to enable blending, the `makeRenderPipelineState` fails with the following error:

> Compiler failed to build request
>   Error Domain=CompilerError Code=1 "Fragment shader does not write to render target color(0), index(1) that is required for blending"

Here's the code that tries to build the pipeline state in the MTKView's delegate. Where it inherits properties from the MTKView, I've put the value of those properties in the comments

```
do {


let descriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
descriptor.vertexFunction = vertex
descriptor.fragmentFunction = fragment
descriptor.sampleCount = view.sampleCount // 4
descriptor.depthAttachmentPixelFormat = view.depthStencilPixelFormat //.depth32Float

let renderAttachment = descriptor.colorAttachments[0]
renderAttachment?.pixelFormat = view.colorPixelFormat //.bgra8Unorm

// following 7 lines cause makeRenderPipelineState to fail
renderAttachment?.isBlendingEnabled = true
renderAttachment?.alphaBlendOperation = .add
renderAttachment?.rgbBlendOperation = .add
renderAttachment?.sourceRGBBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
renderAttachment?.sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
renderAttachment?.destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
renderAttachment?.destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSource1Alpha

computePipelineState = try device.makeComputePipelineState(function: kernel)
renderPipelineState = try device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: descriptor)

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Given that the error complains about `color(0)`, I added the `color[0]` binding to the output of the fragment shader:

```
constant float3 directionalLight = float3(-50, -30, 80);

struct FragOut {
    float4 solidColor [[ color(0) ]];
};

fragment FragOut passThroughFragment(Vertex fragIn [[ stage_in ]]) {
    FragOut fragOut;
    fragOut.solidColor = fragIn.color;
    fragOut.solidColor.rgb *= max(0.4, dot(fragIn.normal, normalize(directionalLight)));
    return fragOut;
};
```

And finally, the draw code:

```
if let renderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor,
    let drawable = view.currentDrawable {
    let commandBuffer = queue.makeCommandBuffer()
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0.8, green: 0.8, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor)
    renderEncoder.setDepthStencilState(depthStencilState)
    renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(renderPipelineState)
    //renderEncoder.setTriangleFillMode(.lines)
    renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(sceneBuffer, offset: 0, at: 0)
    renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, at: 1)           
    renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: Int(vertexCount) ) 

    renderEncoder.endEncoding()
    commandBuffer.present(drawable)
    commandBuffer.commit()
}
```

I don't explicitly set any textures in the fragment shader. Does this mean that the currentDrawable is implicitly the color attachment at index 0? Why does the error message want to see `color(0)` at index 1? Does blending require two color attachments? (it can't just blend additively onto what has already been rendered?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be inadvertently invoking [dual-source blending](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/WhatsNewiniOS10tvOS10andOSX1012/WhatsNewiniOS10tvOS10andOSX1012.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH14-DontLinkElementID_81). Rather than setting the `destinationAlphaBlendFactor` to `oneMinusSource1Alpha`, try `oneMinusSourceAlpha` (note the missing `1`).

Also, your intuition that Metal writes to the first color attachment by default is correct (the current drawable is configured by `MTKView` to be the texture of the first color attachment). Rather than returning a struct with a member that is attributed with `[[color(0)]]`, you can just return a `float4` (or `half4`) from your fragment function, and that color will be written to the primary color attachment. However, the way you've written it should work once your blend factors are configured correctly.

Comment: Oh wow I did not see that `1`! Thanks, it works great now. So is the depth stencil also an implicit colour attachment to the shader? And can I sample the implicit attachments inside the shader if I add them to the function signature? Thanks also for the Metal By Example series, it's a great resource. Do you have plans for a follow-up incorporating MetalKit, Model I/O etc?

Comment: The depth map is a separate type of attachment, but if you've set a depth pixel format on your `MTKView`, the depth texture will also automatically be configured as the depth attachment of the render pass descriptor vended by the view. I don't believe you can sample from the current depth map as you can with color framebuffer fetch (to do programmable blending), though you can provide an explicit depth value rather than using the one implied by the clip space position of the fragment.